# PySpark - Using lists inside LIKE operator

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, sql-like

I would like to use list inside the LIKE operator on pyspark in order to create a column.

I have the following input df :

**`input_df :`**

```
+------+--------------------+-------+
|    ID|           customers|country|
+------+--------------------+-------+
|161   |xyz Limited         |U.K.   |
|262   |ABC  Limited        |U.K.   |
|165   |Sons & Sons         |U.K.   |
|361   |TÜV GmbH            |Germany|
|462   |Mueller GmbH        |Germany|
|369   |Schneider AG        |Germany|
|467   |Sahm UG             |Austria|
+------+--------------------+-------+
```

I would like to add a column CAT_ID. CAT_ID takes value 1 if "ID" contains "16" or "26". CAT_ID takes value 2 if "ID" contains "36" or "46".
So, I want my output df to look like this -

**`The desired output_df :`**

```
+------+--------------------+-------+-------+
|    ID|           customers|country|Cat_ID |
+------+--------------------+-------+-------+
|161   |xyz Limited         |U.K.   |1      |
|262   |ABC  Limited        |U.K.   |1      |
|165   |Sons & Sons         |U.K.   |1      |
|361   |TÜV GmbH            |Germany|2      |
|462   |Mueller GmbH        |Germany|2      |
|369   |Schneider AG        |Germany|2      |
|467   |Sahm UG             |Austria|2      |
+------+--------------------+-------+-------+
```

I am interested in learning how this can be done using LIKE statement and lists.

I know how to implement it without list, which works perfectly:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def add_CAT_ID(df):
    return df.withColumn(
        'CAT_ID', 
        F.when( ( (F.col('ID').like('16%')) | (F.col('ID').like('26%'))  ) , "1") \
         .when( ( (F.col('ID').like('36%')) | (F.col('ID').like('46%'))  ) , "2") \
         .otherwise('999')
    )


    output_df = add_CAT_ID(input_df)
```

However, I would love to use list and have something like:

```
list1 =['16', '26']
list2 =['36', '46']


def add_CAT_ID(df):
    return df.withColumn(
        'CAT_ID', 
        F.when( ( (F.col('ID').like(list1 %))  ) , "1") \
         .when( ( (F.col('ID').like('list2 %'))  ) , "2") \
         .otherwise('999')
    )


    output_df = add_CAT_ID(input_df)
```

Thanks a lot in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL wildcards do not support "or" clauses. There are several ways you can handle it though.

**1. Regular expressions**

You can use `rlike` with a regular expression:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

list1 =['16', '26'] 
list2 =['36', '46']
df.withColumn(
        'CAT_ID', 
        psf.when(psf.col('ID').rlike('({})\d'.format('|'.join(list1))), '1') \
            .when(psf.col('ID').rlike('({})\d'.format('|'.join(list2))), '2') \
            .otherwise('999')) \
    .show()

        +---+------------+-------+------+
        | ID|   customers|country|CAT_ID|
        +---+------------+-------+------+
        |161| xyz Limited|   U.K.|     1|
        |262|ABC  Limited|   U.K.|     1|
        |165| Sons & Sons|   U.K.|     1|
        |361|    TÜV GmbH|Germany|     2|
        |462|Mueller GmbH|Germany|     2|
        |369|Schneider AG|Germany|     2|
        |467|     Sahm UG|Austria|     2|
        +---+------------+-------+------+
```

Here, we get for `list1` the regular expression `(16|26)\d` matching 16 or 26 followed by an integer (`\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]`).

**2. Dynamically build an SQL clause**

If you want to keep the sql like, you can use `selectExpr` and chain the values with `' OR '`:

```py
df.selectExpr(
        '*', 
        "CASE WHEN ({}) THEN '1' WHEN ({}) THEN '2' ELSE '999' END AS CAT_ID"
            .format(*[' OR '.join(["ID LIKE '{}%'".format(x) for x in l]) for l in [list1, list2]]))
```

**3. Dynamically build a Python expression**

You can also use `eval` if you don't want to write SQL:

```py
df.withColumn(
        'CAT_ID', 
        psf.when(eval(" | ".join(["psf.col('ID').like('{}%')".format(x) for x in list1])), '1')
            .when(eval(" | ".join(["psf.col('ID').like('{}%')".format(x) for x in list2])), '2')
            .otherwise('999'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I used the Regular expression and it worked perfectly

Comment: I have an additional question about using lists inside LIKE operator for AND Statement. When I changed `|` into `&`, I didn't get what I want.. `list1 =['6', '2'] `
   `list2 =['6', '4']`
   `df = df.withColumn(
        'CAT_ID', 
        psf.when(psf.col('ID').rlike('({})\d'.format('&'.join(list1))), '1') \
            .when(psf.col('ID').rlike('({})\d'.format('&'.join(list2))), '2') \
            .otherwise('999')
        )`

Comment: Above, I tried to implement such a rule : CAT_ID takes value 1 if "ID" contains "6" and "2". CAT_ID takes value 2 if "ID" contains "6" or "4". For `ID=262`, it didn't have `CAT_ID=1`. Instead, it has `CAT_ID=999`. In the output df, for every row, it gave me `CAT_ID=999`. Thanks a lot in advance @MaFF

Comment: I'll edit my answer to explain how the regular expression works

Comment: The structure of `ID` is in regular expression is `\d{3}` (a sequence of 3 integers). Since each list element in your `AND` clause is only one-integer long you have to add an extra `\d` to the regular exression. '\d(6|2)\d' for if you want to match 6 or 2 in the middle of `ID`. If it's not necessarily in the middle then `'\d{0,2}(6|2)\d{0,2}'`

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanations regarding digit positioning in regex. I was wondering whether there is a way to use regex with any digit position considerations.

Answer (score 1):

With Spark 2.4 onwards, you can use higher order functions in the spark-sql.

Try the below one, the sql solution is same for both scala/python

```
val df = Seq(
  ("161","xyz Limited","U.K."),
  ("262","ABC  Limited","U.K."),
  ("165","Sons & Sons","U.K."),
  ("361","TÜV GmbH","Germany"),
  ("462","Mueller GmbH","Germany"),
  ("369","Schneider AG","Germany"),
  ("467","Sahm UG","Germany")
).toDF("ID","customers","country")

df.show(false)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("secil")
spark.sql(
  """ with t1 ( select id, customers, country, array('16','26') as a1, array('36','46') as a2 from secil),
     t2 (select id, customers, country,  filter(a1, x -> id like x||'%') a1f,  filter(a2, x -> id like x||'%') a2f from t1),
     t3 (select id, customers, country, a1f, a2f,
               case when size(a1f) > 0 then 1 else 0 end a1r,
               case when size(a2f) > 0 then 2 else 0 end a2r
               from t2)
     select id, customers, country, a1f, a2f, a1r, a2r, a1r+a2r as Cat_ID from t3
  """).show(false)
```

**Results:**

```
+---+------------+-------+
|ID |customers   |country|
+---+------------+-------+
|161|xyz Limited |U.K.   |
|262|ABC  Limited|U.K.   |
|165|Sons & Sons |U.K.   |
|361|TÜV GmbH    |Germany|
|462|Mueller GmbH|Germany|
|369|Schneider AG|Germany|
|467|Sahm UG     |Germany|
+---+------------+-------+

+---+------------+-------+----+----+---+---+------+
|id |customers   |country|a1f |a2f |a1r|a2r|Cat_ID|
+---+------------+-------+----+----+---+---+------+
|161|xyz Limited |U.K.   |[16]|[]  |1  |0  |1     |
|262|ABC  Limited|U.K.   |[26]|[]  |1  |0  |1     |
|165|Sons & Sons |U.K.   |[16]|[]  |1  |0  |1     |
|361|TÜV GmbH    |Germany|[]  |[36]|0  |2  |2     |
|462|Mueller GmbH|Germany|[]  |[46]|0  |2  |2     |
|369|Schneider AG|Germany|[]  |[36]|0  |2  |2     |
|467|Sahm UG     |Germany|[]  |[46]|0  |2  |2     |
+---+------------+-------+----+----+---+---+------+
```